# Where is the log file located when verbose history logging is turned on for SQL 2005 replication?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I keep getting the The merge process was unable to create a new generation at the 'Subscriber'. Troubleshoot by restarting the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL-2147200994)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147200994 message.  I went ahead and followed the advice and from the Replication monitor->Agent Profile I changed the profile to Verbose history. Now, where is this file located?  There are not properties in Management studion to sepeify the location. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Merge Replication 
SQL Server 2005 SP2
Troubleshooting

To turn on verbose history (`Replication monitor->Agent Profile->Verbose History`) and use the -output parameter and select a destination for the output file (`Subscriber Replication Job -> Edit Run Agent Job ->In the command window add -output C:\MyFilePath\FileName.log`).

real example:

```
-Publisher [TCP-ODS01] -PublisherDB [concord_ods] -Publication [MERLIN_PUBLICATION] -  
 Subscriber [MERLIN771] -SubscriberDB [ConCORD_ODS]   -Distributor [TCP-MERGE01] -
 DistributorSecurityMode 1 -HostName [MERLIN771]  -output C:\Replication\MERLIN771_1132.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  Just go to the subscribers replication JOB open it up go to steps->Edit Run Agent job(usually the default job created)->under General in the Command window add -Output c:\YourReplicationLog.txt and the file will be on your c drive.